# What is this trio of structures in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

While restoring an abandoned village, I came across these three structures next to what used to be the cartographer's house:

[image: Screenshot of structures.]

What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a structure in the plains biome known as [`Meeting Point 2`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village/Structure/Blueprints/Plains_meeting_point_2_blueprint). It's blueprint is as follows:

| Name | Layer 0 | Layer 1 | Layer 2 | Layer 3 | Layer 4 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grass Path | 53 | - | - | - | - | 53 |
| Grass Block | 54 | - | - | - | - | 54 |
| Dirt | 13 | - | - | - | - | 13 |
| Oak Planks | - | 13 | - | - | - | 13 |
| Oak Fence | - | 12 | 12 | 12 | - | 36 |
| Torch | - | - | 6 | - | - | 6 |
| Bell | - | - | 1 | - | - | 1 |
| Oak Slab | - | - | - | - | 18 | 18 |
| White Wool | - | - | - | - | 9 | 9 |
| Yellow Wool | - | - | - | - | 9 | 9 |

Once completely built with the blueprint, it should look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the results of the blueprint.]

Comment: While that's the 'official name' - as an origin of generation of a village (different villagers have differently styled 'meeting points' - a well, a crossing, a campfire - this one is to depict a marketplace with trading stalls. After village generation (for which it acts as a generic 'central tile'), other than the bell serving as point-of-interest for villagers meeting in the afternoon to trade gossip, it's purely decorative.